# Can an Associated Type be restricted by protocol conformance and a where-clause?

Tags: swift, swift-protocols

I'm trying:

```
public protocol MyProtocol {
    associatedtype MyArray: RangeReplaceableCollectionType where MyArray.Generator.Element == MyType
    //...
}
```

The protocol currently has a property prototype of type `[MyType]`.  Then I decided to generalize it.  So I made an associated type.  I can have it conform to the best container type (`RangeReplaceableCollectionType`) but I get syntax errors when I added the `where` clause.  Is there some (other) way to specify not only that I want a generic container, but restrict its element type?